# Divide data into selected groups in SQL

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to group data based on the value like in example below using sql and clickhouse base

I've got table like the following:

```
    | Module   | MeasTime          | MeasDate  | Variable| Value|
    | ---      | ---               | ---       | ---     | ---  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |
 
 .
 .
 .
```

I need to add a column like below

```
    | Module   | MeasTime          | MeasDate  | Variable| Value|Group id|
    | ---      | ---               | ---       | ---     | ---  |------  |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 00:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |1       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |2       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |2       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |2       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |2       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 01:50:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:00:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:10:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:20:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:30:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   1  |3       |
    |binaryTask|2020-01-02 02:40:00|2020-01-02 |binaryVal|   0  |4       |
 
 .
 .
 .
```

Do you have an idea how i can do this in SQL in a good performing way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share create table / insert sample data / desired result?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake, I've edited my question

Comment: How should the values in `Group_Id` column be generated? And can you post the DDL that is used for creating the first table?

Comment: @T0ny1234 values are from clickhouse databased and generated besides of me. Group ID need to be generated indyvidally for each state and change for every value changes from 1->0 and 0->1 in Value column.

Comment: @TheRocky As seen [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/show/) this is the way you can generate the DDL.

Comment: I don't see DDL / Insert